# createUrl doesn't work correctly within extended CBaseUrlRule class

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I made my own class that extends CBaseUrlRule to manage some sort of pages on site. Result class code is

```
class HotelUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule {

public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo) {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        if (($_GET['id'] != 0) && ($pathInfo == 'hotel')) {
            return 'hotel/index';
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand) {

    if ($route == 'hotel/index') {
        Yii::import('application.controllers.SearchController');
        $searcher = new SearchController($this, NULL);
        $hotelRaw = $searcher->actionGetHotelInformation($_GET['id']);
        $hotelRaw = $hotelRaw['GetHotelInformationResult'];
        $hotelName = $hotelRaw['Name'];
        $hotelName = preg_replace('%(\s)%', '-', $hotelName);
        return 'hotel/' . $hotelName;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

The condition in parseUrl ($_GET['id'] != 0) && ($pathInfo == 'hotel') returns 'true' and the condition in createUrl ($route == 'hotel/index') returns 'false'. Var_dump of $route is 'admin/auth'.

Why is it so? Any guesses?